# Navigation Not Lining Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the flexnav jquery plugin. I got it working, but the list is not lining up. See attached image. I do not know why it is doing this since I have not altered the code in any way BUT on the demo site it lines up just right.
Here is a link to the css source code on github: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/indyplanets/flexnav/master/css/flexnav.css

I've tried changing the position property. I can't seem to find a solution to my issue. I'm basically lost at this point. If anyone can help me to fix this I would appreciate it.

The flexnav plugin is located at http://jasonweaver.name/lab/flexiblenavigation/ and there is a demo on the page.

[image]

```js
/*
     FlexNav.js 1.3.3
    
     Created by Jason Weaver http://jasonweaver.name
     Released under http://unlicense.org/
    
    //
    */


(function() {
  var $;

  $ = jQuery;

  $.fn.flexNav = function(options) {
    var $nav, $top_nav_items, breakpoint, count, nav_percent, nav_width, resetMenu, resizer, settings, showMenu, toggle_selector, touch_selector;
    settings = $.extend({
      'animationSpeed': 250,
      'transitionOpacity': true,
      'buttonSelector': '.menu-button',
      'hoverIntent': false,
      'hoverIntentTimeout': 150,
      'calcItemWidths': false,
      'hover': true
    }, options);
    $nav = $(this);
    $nav.addClass('with-js');
    if (settings.transitionOpacity === true) {
      $nav.addClass('opacity');
    }
    $nav.find("li").each(function() {
      if ($(this).has("ul").length) {
        return $(this).addClass("item-with-ul").find("ul").hide();
      }
    });
    if (settings.calcItemWidths === true) {
      $top_nav_items = $nav.find('>li');
      count = $top_nav_items.length;
      nav_width = 100 / count;
      nav_percent = nav_width + "%";
    }
    if ($nav.data('breakpoint')) {
      breakpoint = $nav.data('breakpoint');
    }
    showMenu = function() {
      if ($nav.hasClass('lg-screen') === true && settings.hover === true) {
        if (settings.transitionOpacity === true) {
          return $(this).find('>ul').addClass('flexnav-show').stop(true, true).animate({
            height: ["toggle", "swing"],
            opacity: "toggle"
          }, settings.animationSpeed);
        } else {
          return $(this).find('>ul').addClass('flexnav-show').stop(true, true).animate({
            height: ["toggle", "swing"]
          }, settings.animationSpeed);
        }
      }
    };
    resetMenu = function() {
      if ($nav.hasClass('lg-screen') === true && $(this).find('>ul').hasClass('flexnav-show') === true && settings.hover === true) {
        if (settings.transitionOpacity === true) {
          return $(this).find('>ul').removeClass('flexnav-show').stop(true, true).animate({
            height: ["toggle", "swing"],
            opacity: "toggle"
          }, settings.animationSpeed);
        } else {
          return $(this).find('>ul').removeClass('flexnav-show').stop(true, true).animate({
            height: ["toggle", "swing"]
          }, settings.animationSpeed);
        }
      }
    };
    resizer = function() {
      var selector;
      if ($(window).width() <= breakpoint) {
        $nav.removeClass("lg-screen").addClass("sm-screen");
        if (settings.calcItemWidths === true) {
          $top_nav_items.css('width', '100%');
        }
        selector = settings['buttonSelector'] + ', ' + settings['buttonSelector'] + ' .touch-button';
        $(selector).removeClass('active');
        return $('.one-page li a').on('click', function() {
          return $nav.removeClass('flexnav-show');
        });
      } else if ($(window).width() > breakpoint) {
        $nav.removeClass("sm-screen").addClass("lg-screen");
        if (settings.calcItemWidths === true) {
          $top_nav_items.css('width', nav_percent);
        }
        $nav.removeClass('flexnav-show').find('.item-with-ul').on();
        $('.item-with-ul').find('ul').removeClass('flexnav-show');
        resetMenu();
        if (settings.hoverIntent === true) {
          return $('.item-with-ul').hoverIntent({
            over: showMenu,
            out: resetMenu,
            timeout: settings.hoverIntentTimeout
          });
        } else if (settings.hoverIntent === false) {
          return $('.item-with-ul').on('mouseenter', showMenu).on('mouseleave', resetMenu);
        }
      }
    };
    $(settings['buttonSelector']).data('navEl', $nav);
    touch_selector = '.item-with-ul, ' + settings['buttonSelector'];
    $(touch_selector).append('<span class="touch-button"><span class="navicon">&vellip;</span></span>');
    toggle_selector = settings['buttonSelector'] + ', ' + settings['buttonSelector'] + ' .touch-button';
    $(toggle_selector).on('click', function(e) {
      var $btnParent, $thisNav, bs;
      $(toggle_selector).toggleClass('active');
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      bs = settings['buttonSelector'];
      $btnParent = $(this).is(bs) ? $(this) : $(this).parent(bs);
      $thisNav = $btnParent.data('navEl');
      return $thisNav.toggleClass('flexnav-show');
    });
    $('.touch-button').on('click', function(e) {
      var $sub, $touchButton;
      $sub = $(this).parent('.item-with-ul').find('>ul');
      $touchButton = $(this).parent('.item-with-ul').find('>span.touch-button');
      if ($nav.hasClass('lg-screen') === true) {
        $(this).parent('.item-with-ul').siblings().find('ul.flexnav-show').removeClass('flexnav-show').hide();
      }
      if ($sub.hasClass('flexnav-show') === true) {
        $sub.removeClass('flexnav-show').slideUp(settings.animationSpeed);
        return $touchButton.removeClass('active');
      } else if ($sub.hasClass('flexnav-show') === false) {
        $sub.addClass('flexnav-show').slideDown(settings.animationSpeed);
        return $touchButton.addClass('active');
      }
    });
    $nav.find('.item-with-ul *').focus(function() {
      $(this).parent('.item-with-ul').parent().find(".open").not(this).removeClass("open").hide();
      return $(this).parent('.item-with-ul').find('>ul').addClass("open").show();
    });
    resizer();
    return $(window).on('resize', resizer);
  };

}).call(this);
```

```css
/* Flexnav Base Styles */

* {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.flexnav {
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -ms-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
}
.flexnav.opacity {
  opacity: 0;
}
.flexnav.flexnav-show {
  max-height: 2000px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.flexnav.one-page {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  right: 5%;
  max-width: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}
.flexnav li {
  font-size: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flexnav li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: .96em;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #000000;
  background: #ff69b4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.flexnav li ul {
  width: 100%;
}
.flexnav li ul li {
  font-size: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flexnav li ul.flexnav-show li {
  overflow: visible;
}
.flexnav li ul li a {
  display: block;
  background: #b2b2af;
}
.flexnav ul li ul li a {
  background: #bfbfbc;
}
.flexnav ul li ul li ul li a {
  background: #cbcbc9;
}
.flexnav .touch-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #acaca1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  text-align: center;
}
.flexnav .touch-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.flexnav .touch-button .navicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1.4em;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666;
}
.menu-button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #ff69b4;
  font-family: Lobster;
  color: #0000;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ff69b4, #FFC0CB);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#ff69b4, #FFC0CB);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#ff69b4, #FFC0CB);
  background: linear-gradient(#ff69b4, #FFC0CB);
}
.menu-button.one-page {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 5%;
  padding-right: 45px;
}
.menu-button .touch-button {
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu-button .touch-button .navicon {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
  color: #666;
}
@media all and (min-width: 1800px) {
  body.one-page {
    padding-top: 70px;
  }
  .flexnav {
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .flexnav.opacity {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .flexnav.one-page {
    top: 0;
    right: auto;
    max-width: 1080px;
  }
  .flexnav li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background-color: #a6a6a2;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 20%;
  }
  .flexnav li a {
    border-left: 1px solid #acaca1;
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .flexnav li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    left: 0;
  }
  .flexnav li > ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .flexnav li ul li > ul {
    margin-left: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }
  .flexnav li ul li a {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .flexnav li ul.open {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .flexnav li ul.open li {
    overflow: visible;
    max-height: 100px;
  }
  .flexnav li ul.open ul.open {
    margin-left: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }
  .menu-button {
    display: none;
  }
}
.oldie body.one-page {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
.oldie .flexnav {
  overflow: visible;
}
.oldie .flexnav.one-page {
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  max-width: 1080px;
}
.oldie .flexnav li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background-color: #a6a6a2;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 50px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.oldie .flexnav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}
.oldie .flexnav li:hover > ul li {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
}
.oldie .flexnav li a {
  border-left: 1px solid #acaca1;
  border-bottom: none;
  overflow: visible;
}
.oldie .flexnav li > ul {
  background: #acaca1;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: visible;
}
.oldie .flexnav li ul li ul {
  top: 0;
}
.oldie .flexnav li ul li a {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.oldie .flexnav li ul.open {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}
.oldie .flexnav li ul.open li {
  width: 100%;
}
.oldie .flexnav li ul.open ul.open {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}
.oldie .flexnav ul li:hover ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.oldie .menu-button {
  display: none;
}
.oldie.ie7 .flexnav li {
  width: 19.9%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <div class="menu-button">Menu</div>
  <ul class="flexnav" data-breakpoint="800">
    <li>
      <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="dispatch.php">Request Pilot Cars</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="invoice.php">Submit Invoice</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="gallery.php">Photos</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Jesse! Screenshots are great, as they help us  visualize what is happening, but without seeing your code (CSS, HTML, JS) we can't really do much to help you.

Comment: Would you prefer me to link you to the test page so you can view literally everything? :) http://m.hoosiermommapcs.com/test.php

Comment: Actually, it would be best if you could copy and paste your code here, splitting it out into sections for CSS, HTML and JS, respectively. If there is any unrelated code or content, you can remove it or replace it with a comment about what was removed. Otherwise, it just tends to be a bit too much to look through.

Comment: Oh I was just suggesting that because there is nothing else on the page with the menu except for the logo lol Is there a fast way to indent code 4 spaces? This is a good bit to post on here.

Comment: Select what you want to indent and click the ' {} ' icon

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip also. I cannot count the times I went line by line adding four spaces. I was unaware of that feature. :)

Comment: Dmitriy actually found the solution. It was fairly simple yet overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add  `ul` class .flexnav -  `padding: 0;`

Comment: Works. Thanks. I can't believe it was that simple. I figured since the demo page worked fine and i used their code then it must have been something else than that. :)